# How to inject a JPA repository for multiple datasources in micronaut-data?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have a micronaut-data application and for a copy operation I need to use the same JPA repository to access multiple datasources. I would like to inject them into different variable, e.g. `sourceRepo` and `targetRepo`. The datasources are declared in the `application.yml` with the names *default* and *target*. If I declare a repository variable with `@Inject` it will be initialized to access the *default* datasource.

The question is, how can I declare an injected repository variable so that it will access the *target* datasource? I can declare *target* injections of `EntityManager` or `SynchronousTransactionManager` like below and these work. But neither of these annotations has an effect on a repository variable or parameter.

```java
    @Inject
    @CurrentSession("target")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext(name = "target")
    SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection> transactionManager;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: currently (as of micronaut-data 1.0.0.RC1) injecting repositories directly for different datasources is not possible. Instead, the `@Repository` annotation optionally accepts a datasource name (e.g. `@Repository("target")`. This means that to use a repository on different repositories, it needs to be declared in a specific class. To use such a repository an instance of the respective class needs to be injected into the using code.

Changing this has been proposed [in the micronaut-data project](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/368)  and is under consideration.